# How to edit category page layout?

Tags: mediawiki

How do I edit the layout for a category page, such as the they use on: http://gwpvx.gamepedia.com/Category:Meta_working_PvP_builds

(Image: http://i.gyazo.com/04337c415c7e67d766003bf02a598d1a.png)

I would like to add html code at the exact same where they have the ad but on my own wiki. This code should only be visible in categories.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple, built in way to alter the category pages. Adding the ad with Javascript from `MediaWiki:Common.js` would probably be easiest for you.

That said, if you really need to alter the HTML code of the page, the hook [CategoryPageView](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/CategoryPageView) is what you are looking for.

Something like this:

```
$wgHooks['CategoryPageView'][] = 'insertAdInCategoryPage';

public static function insertAdInCategoryPage( &$categoryArticle ) { 

  global $wgOut;
  $wgOut->addHTML(/*some HTML*/);
  return true;

}
```

`$categoryArticle` will be a [article](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Article.php) object.